# RewriteRule with greedy matches trying to redirect root to a page, and rewrite all other requests to https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to work with apache2 rewrite to perform two functions

1. rewrite (or redirect) / (root) requests to a specific page: /index
2. all requests (including / and /index) on port 80, are rewritten to HTTPS

Here is my failed attempt

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%/index [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

My guess is that the last rule was being too aggressive/greedy (everything is rewriting to https) - so I tried to prevent the root match from getting there by adding a RewriteCond that matches on not root, but it is not working.

Edit: is my approach wrong?  Is there an obvious mistake in Rules/Conditions?

Comment: Care to comment on the down vote?  I would gladly clarify the question, or rephrase given a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$

This will always match, %{REQUEST_URI} does not have the current per-directory prefix removed from it like the implicit thing you match a per-directory RewriteRule against.  IOW add the slash in.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is the final configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%/index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```